# ListView Previous and Next Button

Tags: android

I am using listView to change the value
here is my code. But It's not going to stop. when Listview last index no. suppose 10 then, it's crash. how do i stop next button when listView end.

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txtOne.setText(letter[lastView+1]);
            txtTwo.setText(letterDetails[lastView+1]);
            txtThree.setText(letterB[lastView+1]);

            lastView++;

            if (lastView == letter.length){
                lastView=0;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lastView+" ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtOne.setText(letter[lastView-1]);
            txtTwo.setText(letterDetails[lastView-1]);
            txtThree.setText(letterB[lastView-1]);
            lastView--;
        }
    });
```

Comment: And the **previousBtn** when listView index no 0 then if i click previ button program crashed. What can I do now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically letter.length return size of array. Suppose you have 10 items in array then the index will be 0-9.The reason behind your app is crashing is due to array out of bound error.
What you have to do is just add this line in your if condition.

**Code**

```
if (lastView == (letter.length-1))
```

Comment: it's work bro, Thanks a lot, i just create a **else if** and in the if condition `lastView<9` **else if**  and your given codition, thanks bro